# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, typeerror

I'm trying to make a project in HTML Canvas but am encountering this error repeatedly. I get it 1) when I use `document.createElement` and then call `canvas.getContext` 2) when I create `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` and then use `document.getElementById` and then do `canvas.getContext`
Here is the my code:

`HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pythagoras Theorum Proof</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`JS`:

```
/**
 * @type {HTMLCanvasElement}
 */
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
/**
 * @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D}
 */
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

(window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.width = window.innerHeight
}))()

canvas.style.border = "2px solid black"
```

(I need the JSDoc to identify `canvas` as `HTMLCanvasElement` and `ctx` as `CanvasRenderingContext2D` as I use VS Code and need help of its intelliscience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few semicolons and I also ensured that the `addEventListener`'s return value is not call. You add an event listener for resize, which is cool. Don't call the result, because `addEventListener` does not return anything, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, that is, it returns `undefined`, which is not a function and therefore you cannot call it.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
  console.log("resized");
});

canvas.style.border = "2px solid black";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

EDIT

Since in the comment section I was asked for a more thorough explanation and the initial version of this answer was more of an operative character, I have a theoretical debt of providing this explanation, so here it goes.

This is where the original code breaks:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

(window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.width = window.innerHeight
}))()
```

The reason for the problem is that without the `;` after `const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")`, the code looks like this for the compiler:

```
const foo = wunder.bar()
(some.func("something", () => {
    //some things
}))()
```

So, the compiler assumes that the `wunder.bar()` returns a `function`, which you call, passing the result of `some.func(...)`, which is another function and you call it with the last paranthesis of `()`.

Example:

```js
let wunder = {
    bar: () => {console.log("Das ist wunderbar")}
};

let some = {
    func: function(text, callback) {
        return function() {
            console.log('fantastic!');
        }
    }
};

function test(mode) {
    if (mode) {
        const foo = wunder.bar()
        (some.func("something", function(txt) {
        }))();
    } else {
        const foo = wunder.bar();
        (some.func("something", function(txt) {
        }))();
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="error" onclick="test(1)">
<input type="button" value="success" onclick="test(0)">
```

Read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semicolon-in-javascript/

Comment: This somehow solves the issue but I cant see why

Comment: @Zayaan first, you needed semicolon of `;` at the end of the lines where `canvas` and `ctx` are defined. Next, you need to simply call `window.addEventListener("resize", () => {/*some commands*/});` instead of calling its return value as a function like `window.addEventListener("resize", () => {/*some commands*/})()` and you need semicolon at the end of this line as well.

Comment: Aren't semi-colons optional in javascript (when they are at the end of the line)? I understood what to change but not how it actually made sense intuitively (it is ok if it's not even intuitive, but at least it is not understandable)

Comment: @Zayaan semi-colons are optional in theory. But, in practice, when the lack of semi-colon can be understood differently from the one you intended, the compiler may choose the undesired interpretation. In our case it viewed the paranthesis in the next line of the `canvas.getContext("2d")` call as calling a function that `canvas.getContext("2d")` returns and then calling a function this second function returned.

Comment: @Zayaan please take a look at my edited answer, I have provided more information and explanation as well as a new snippet for the sake of clarity of this specific issue.